# C# guid and SQL uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, sql, guid, uniqueidentifier

I want to create a GUID and store it in the DB.

In C# a guid can be created using Guid.NewGuid().  This creates a 128 bit integer.  SQL Server has a uniqueidentifier column which holds a huge hexidecimal number.

Is there a good/preferred way to make C# and SQL Server guids play well together? (i.e. create a guid using Guid.New() and then store it in the database using nvarchar or some other field ... or create some hexidecimal number of the form that SQL Server is expecting by some other means)

Comment: Do NOT use nvarchar, use uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

SQL is expecting the GUID as a string. The following in C# returns a string Sql is expecting.

```
"'" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "'"
```

Something like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (GuidID) VALUE ('4b5e95a7-745a-462f-ae53-709a8583700a')
```

is what it should look like in SQL.

Comment: If you use SqlParameter, you don't have to convert the GUID into a string.

Comment: To be clearer to everyone, I'm not suggesting that the sql specified should be used as demonstrated from C# with string concatenation. The crux of the question, I believe, is what form does a SQL UNIQUEIDENTIFIER LITERAL look like. The literal looks just like a string but with a special format. The two code snippets demonstrate what the literal looks like in 2 languages. 

I agree with DLKG that using a parameterized query and passing the guid as a typed parameter is both more performant as well as preventing potential SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: And in Entity Framework, Database first method, a `uniqueidentifier` SQL datatype (recommended in comment by @TorHaugen) translates to a `System.Guid` C# datatype, which is what OP asked about

Comment: so how does System.Guid generates an identifier that is not already in the DB ? although, the odds would be small...is there a check for uniqueness ?

Answer (score 72):

Here's a code snippet showing how to insert a GUID using a parameterised query:

```
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Transaction = trans;
            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([GuidValue]) VALUE @guidValue;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guidValue", Guid.NewGuid());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: guidValue should be @guidValue

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the correct way to do it, rather than just answering the question literally.

Comment: Very useful. I was trying to parse a string etc... inside the database. This works great. Cheers, ~ck

Comment: This works for inserting but not for a `WHERE` clause. It tries to compare the lowercase `guid` from c# to the uppercase `uniqueidentifier` and that doesn't match.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a C# Guid value directly to a SQL Stored Procedure by specifying `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier`.

Your method may look like this (provided that your only parameter is the Guid):

```
public static void StoreGuid(Guid guid)
{
    using (var cnx = new SqlConnection("YourDataBaseConnectionString"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand {
        Connection = cnx,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = "StoreGuid",
        Parameters = {
            new SqlParameter {
                ParameterName = "@guid",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, // right here
                Value = guid
            }
        }
    })
    {
        cnx.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

<sub>See also: SQL Server's [`uniqueidentifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Store it in the database in a field with a data type of uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create Instance of Connection and Command Object
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(GentEFONRFFConnection);
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("your Procedure Name", myConnection);
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@orgid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = orgid;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@statid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = statid;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@read", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = read;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@write", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = write;
// Mark the Command as a SPROC

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

myCommand.Dispose();
myConnection.Close();
```