# GUIDs in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, guid

I have an ASP.NET application that generates GUIDs in the code-behind via C#. These GUIDs are generated via the following:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

This GUID is later stored in a SQL Server 2008 database. I also have a stored procedure that will update that record. I would like to generate a GUID in the stored procedure that is in the same format as the one generated in ASP.NET.

Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same format"? GUIDs are binary - a series of 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a clustered index (most often a primary key), I highly recommend [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) (SQL Server 2005 on up) since, `NEWID()` will create a fragmented index in that case, being truly random.

Comment: And `newsequentialid()` can only be specified as a default constraint on a column - you cannot just call it.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) method

```
DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier
SET @ID = NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a GUID for you: `SELECT NEWID()`

Examples may be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NEWID()`.

But, there are issues with indexing guids generated like this. Instead, you should use the [comb algorithm](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862&seqNum=7):

```
CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(10)) +
    CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(6)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Make sure you are storing these in a column of type `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and not converting them to `NVARCHAR` or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

My guess from the way that you have worded your question is that you are storing the GUIDs in a text (e.g. `VARCHAR`) field in the database - if this is the case then you should instead be using the `uniqueidentifier` type in which case you can use the `NEWID()` SQL function to generate a new GUID.

See [C# guid and SQL uniqueidentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435908/c-guid-and-sql-uniqueidentifier) for more detail on how to store GUIDs in an SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NEWSEQUENTIALID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) for better indexing support, but the downside is that you can use this function only as a default value expression for your column.

You can use something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTABLE (...) OUTPUT inserted.GUIDCOLUMN INTO @tableVar VALUES (...)
```

to access the newly generated sequential id.