# SQL Server UniqueIdentifier type - reproduce in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following SQL server code that I need to reproduce in c#:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HashPassword] 
( 
@Password VARCHAR(50), 
@PasswordSalt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
) 
RETURNS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
AS 

BEGIN 
DECLARE @HashPassword UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
SELECT @HashPassword = HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST(@Password as varbinary) + CAST(@PasswordSalt as varbinary)) 
RETURN(@HashPassword) 
END
```

So I got as far as the following:

```
string passwordShortened =  HexStringShortened(password);
string saltShortened =  HexStringShortened(salt);
var concated = passwordShortened.FromHexEncoded().Concat(saltShortened.FromHexEncoded()).ToArray();
SHA1 hasher = SHA1.Create();
byte[] hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(concated);
string convertedFinal = ByteArrayToString(hashBytes);


private static string HexStringShortened(string cleartext)
{
    byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(cleartext);
    var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    hexString = hexString.Replace("-", "");
    if (hexString.Length > 59)
    {
        hexString = hexString.Substring(0, 60);
    }
    return hexString;
}
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
   string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
   return hex.Replace("-", "");
}
```

But the problem now is that the SQL code returns UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and not bytes. If I change it to return as is, without casting :

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST('Password2@' as varbinary)+CAST('84BD070D-F062-4DF5-AB3F-5BBC2D6A9039' as varbinary) )     as simplehash1
```

then I get the same result in c# and in SQL Server.

But in case SQL returns UniqueIdentifier I have no clue what should I do in C#. I tried parsing GUID from the byte array I receive at hashBytes but got nowhere. Any advice?

Comment: it's GUID in C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435908/c-sharp-guid-and-sql-uniqueidentifier

Comment: Run `select CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,0x0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F10)` to get a feel for how SQL Server converts a varbinary (which is what `HASHBYTES` returns) into a uniqueidentifier. Note that you get the same bytes but displayed in a different order. Just mess with your current `byte` array and the `Guid` constructors until you get the same result.