# How to avoid 'the same signature error' in interface?

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

I am modeling domain-interfaces for n-tier application and preparing interface **ICustomerRepository**.
Inside I have a plenty of signatures and two of them faced with 'same signature' error.

```
    Customer GetCustomer(string guid, CustomerInformationLevel informationLevel
        = CustomerInformationLevel.AccountInformation);

    Customer GetCustomer(string firstName, string lastName, string middleName,
        CustomerInformationLevel informationLevel
            = CustomerInformationLevel.AccountInformation);

    Customer GetCustomer(string email, CustomerInformationLevel informationLevel
        = CustomerInformationLevel.AccountInformation);
```

And signatures with **string** **'guid' and 'email'** conflicts. I know why it happens but don't know how to avoid it in **context of the right architecture and design principles**.

Comment: Maybe using type `Guid` for parameter `guid`?

Comment: Or have methods called `GetCustomerById`, `GetCustomerByName` and `GetCustomerByEmail`.

Comment: Or rather use Email class for email, since it makes sense to have validation for it inside its own class later.

Comment: `string[] names` for the 2nd one would be another way. different method names makes it clearer though

Comment: These two methods have the exact same signature. Parameter names do not contribute to the method signature. So you won't get different signatures by having different parameter names.

Comment: Thanks you all for suggestions. I wonder what the best one as 'the right design' ? Store guid as guid type or add different names to methods? Or something else?

Comment: @IskanderRaimbayev I don't think there's any such thing as 'the right design'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `Guid` instead `string` in first method and then `Guid` variable parse to string.
2. you can use the same method for guid and email and check what type of parameter is passed inside this method (using regex or check if string contains '@' symbol) and process by specific way for email and guid.
3. set different names for first and third methods

If you want the same name for methods, you should choose first or second option.

- If you store guids in strings in your application it will be better to use second option.
- If it is unimportant what type to use (`Guid` or `string`) then first option will be better (but it is my opinion)

Comment: I will use code-first with Entity Framework, so I thought storing guid as string will be more performance-optimized for EF and MS SQL. Am I right or there is no difference between guid\string types to map into MS SQL?

Comment: SQL type for Guid is string - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435908/c-sharp-guid-and-sql-uniqueidentifier