# Create a consistant GUID or unique identifier from a string

Tags: c#

Say I have a string, something like '70c3bdc5ceeac673'. Is it possible in C# to create a GUID like structure (DB Column is only accepting uniqueidentifier) based on this string? The goal would be that the same Guid or unique sting is created everytime I pass that value in. I guess essentially like a Hmac SHA1 hash with a key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# guid and SQL uniqueidentifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435908/c-sharp-guid-and-sql-uniqueidentifier)

Comment: @Jack That answer is about creating a storing guids in sql server, I have no issues with that but I need to be able to create the same exact guid based off of the `70c3bdc5ceeac673` string. Basically as form of encryption.

Comment: The `Guid` class has a constructor that takes a string. You'd just have to come up with some scheme for widening inputs that are too short: your example has only 64 bits while a GUID needs 128. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Basically I want the same string to always be transformed to the same Guid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating `Guid` from SHA256 hash seem like an easy option:

```
var guid = new Guid(
   System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create()
      .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("70c3bdc5ceeac673")).Take(16).ToArray());
```

Code discards half of hash result, but it does not change the fact that the same string is always transformed to the same Guid.

Alternatively depending on your requirements just converting string to byte array and padding with 0/removing extra may be enough.

Comment: This may be what I need. The initial string is going to be a device UUID as long as that string is always transformed to the same guid that should be all I need. I'll test it out.

Comment: Maybe MD5 would fit better here since it already creates a 128 but result so no need to cut...

Comment: Consider using static SHA256.HashData instead of creating Sha256 instance

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all your strings are within 16 non-wide chars (as `70c3bdc5ceeac673`), you can use this:

```
// value is your string

var bytes = new byte[16];
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value, 0, value.Length, bytes, 0);
var guid = new Guid(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to the Alexei Levenkov's answer, we can use SHA1, SHA256 or MD5 for similar result.

Here are the code for any of that algorithms

SHA256 (Note: for this algorithms we need to slice hash to the first 16 bytes)

```
public static Guid CreateSha256Deterministic(ReadOnlySpan<char> input)
{
  var byteSpan = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(input);
  Span<byte> hash = SHA256.HashData(byteSpan);
  var guid = new Guid(hash[..16]);
  return guid;
}
```

Sha1 (Note: for this algorithms we need to slice hash to the first 16 bytes)

```
public static Guid CreateSha1Deterministic(ReadOnlySpan<char> input)
{
  var byteSpan = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(input);
  Span<byte> hash = SHA1.HashData(byteSpan);
  var guid = new Guid(hash[..16]);
  return guid;
}
```

MD5 (Generates exactly 16 bytes, no need to slice)

```
public static Guid CreateMd5Deterministic(ReadOnlySpan<char> input)
{
  var byteSpan = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(input);
  Span<byte> hash = MD5.HashData(byteSpan);
  var guid = new Guid(hash);
  return guid;
}
```

I've made some benchmarks and here are the results:

| Method | StringLength | Mean | Error | StdDev | StdErr | Min | Q1 | Median | Q3 | Max | Op/s | Ratio | Gen0 | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GenerateSha256 | 5 | 185.6 ns | 0.19 ns | 0.17 ns | 0.04 ns | 185.3 ns | 185.5 ns | 185.6 ns | 185.7 ns | 185.9 ns | 5,387,435.7 | 0.65 | 0.0088 | 56 B | 1.75 |
| GenerateSha1 | 5 | 194.9 ns | 0.14 ns | 0.12 ns | 0.03 ns | 194.8 ns | 194.8 ns | 194.9 ns | 195.0 ns | 195.2 ns | 5,130,572.6 | 0.69 | 0.0076 | 48 B | 1.50 |
| GenerateMd5 | 5 | 281.3 ns | 0.17 ns | 0.15 ns | 0.04 ns | 281.1 ns | 281.1 ns | 281.2 ns | 281.4 ns | 281.6 ns | 3,555,333.5 | 0.99 | 0.0062 | 40 B | 1.25 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GenerateSha256 | 10 | 171.3 ns | 0.15 ns | 0.13 ns | 0.04 ns | 171.1 ns | 171.2 ns | 171.3 ns | 171.4 ns | 171.5 ns | 5,838,189.6 | 0.63 | 0.0088 | 56 B | 1.40 |
| GenerateSha1 | 10 | 180.1 ns | 0.22 ns | 0.21 ns | 0.05 ns | 179.7 ns | 180.0 ns | 180.1 ns | 180.2 ns | 180.5 ns | 5,551,371.9 | 0.66 | 0.0076 | 48 B | 1.20 |
| GenerateMd5 | 10 | 266.8 ns | 0.16 ns | 0.15 ns | 0.04 ns | 266.6 ns | 266.7 ns | 266.8 ns | 266.9 ns | 267.1 ns | 3,747,426.0 | 0.98 | 0.0062 | 40 B | 1.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GenerateSha256 | 50 | 158.0 ns | 0.10 ns | 0.10 ns | 0.02 ns | 157.8 ns | 157.9 ns | 158.0 ns | 158.0 ns | 158.1 ns | 6,330,634.1 | 0.36 | 0.0088 | 56 B | 0.70 |
| GenerateSha1 | 50 | 171.9 ns | 0.25 ns | 0.24 ns | 0.06 ns | 171.6 ns | 171.7 ns | 171.9 ns | 172.0 ns | 172.4 ns | 5,818,184.1 | 0.39 | 0.0076 | 48 B | 0.60 |
| GenerateMd5 | 50 | 336.9 ns | 0.26 ns | 0.23 ns | 0.06 ns | 336.6 ns | 336.7 ns | 336.8 ns | 336.9 ns | 337.4 ns | 2,968,588.7 | 0.76 | 0.0062 | 40 B | 0.50 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GenerateSha256 | 100 | 236.9 ns | 0.20 ns | 0.18 ns | 0.05 ns | 236.6 ns | 236.8 ns | 236.9 ns | 237.0 ns | 237.2 ns | 4,220,668.9 | 0.63 | 0.0086 | 56 B | 0.44 |
| GenerateSha1 | 100 | 264.2 ns | 0.15 ns | 0.14 ns | 0.04 ns | 264.0 ns | 264.1 ns | 264.2 ns | 264.3 ns | 264.5 ns | 3,784,571.8 | 0.71 | 0.0076 | 48 B | 0.38 |
| GenerateMd5 | 100 | 615.4 ns | 0.40 ns | 0.37 ns | 0.10 ns | 614.7 ns | 615.3 ns | 615.5 ns | 615.8 ns | 615.9 ns | 1,624,851.0 | 1.65 | 0.0057 | 40 B | 0.31 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GenerateSha256 | 500 | 497.5 ns | 0.39 ns | 0.36 ns | 0.09 ns | 496.9 ns | 497.2 ns | 497.3 ns | 497.7 ns | 498.2 ns | 2,010,174.9 | 0.38 | 0.0086 | 56 B | 0.11 |
| GenerateSha1 | 500 | 515.3 ns | 0.38 ns | 0.36 ns | 0.09 ns | 514.6 ns | 515.1 ns | 515.4 ns | 515.5 ns | 515.9 ns | 1,940,688.7 | 0.39 | 0.0076 | 48 B | 0.09 |
| GenerateMd5 | 500 | 1,975.4 ns | 1.76 ns | 1.56 ns | 0.42 ns | 1,972.2 ns | 1,974.8 ns | 1,975.5 ns | 1,976.0 ns | 1,978.3 ns | 506,216.5 | 1.50 | 0.0038 | 40 B | 0.08 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GenerateSha256 | 1000 | 947.8 ns | 0.24 ns | 0.21 ns | 0.06 ns | 947.5 ns | 947.6 ns | 947.7 ns | 947.9 ns | 948.2 ns | 1,055,086.2 | 0.41 | 0.0086 | 56 B | 0.05 |
| GenerateSha1 | 1000 | 967.4 ns | 0.80 ns | 0.75 ns | 0.19 ns | 966.3 ns | 966.9 ns | 967.1 ns | 967.9 ns | 968.9 ns | 1,033,722.4 | 0.41 | 0.0076 | 48 B | 0.05 |
| GenerateMd5 | 1000 | 3,890.4 ns | 2.67 ns | 2.50 ns | 0.65 ns | 3,884.4 ns | 3,889.1 ns | 3,890.8 ns | 3,892.0 ns | 3,894.7 ns | 257,042.5 | 1.67 | - | 40 B | 0.04 |

As we can see, best approach is to use SHA1 or SHA256