# Conversion error (string to uniqueidentifier) when trying to store guid

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am providing my code please help me,

When I am trying to get `xml` data and store in `SQL` at that time I am getting the error "Conversion failed"

```
foreach (entity ent in _entity) 
{               
    con.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO tblDemo (ContractType,P2P_Request_SYSID,EntityName,SYSID,ETag,Name,EntityInstanceId,EntityVersion) Values ('" + ent.Type+"','" +ent.P2P_Request_SYSID + "','" + ent.EntityName + "','" + ent.SYSID + "','" + ent.ETag + "','" + ent.Name + "','" + ent.EntityInstanceId + "','" + ent.EntityVersion + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Which column is the type uniqueidentifier and what value are you passing to it? For example `B14BC077-F1DF-457C-9F7E-7CB9E0BC1CF3` would work but `123456` would give you this error.

Comment: First, use query parameters.  Second, if you are using c# to generate your guid, store it as a string.

Comment: hi Equialsk,  P2P_Request_SYSID, SYSID and EntityInstanceId three column have uniqueidentier datatype.

Comment: B14BC077-F1DF-457C-9F7E-7CB9E0BC1CF3 my data format

Comment: Dan Bracuk i can't understand your suggestion please

Comment: FYI it cannot convert an `Empty` or `NULL` string to a `uniqueidentifier`, so you might get that error.

Comment: Rahul any way ? to solve this problem?

Comment: Debug and check what value you are getting in the `uniqueidentifier` column. If you are getting it blank then anyway it will throw said error. If you are getting value in  `uniqueidentifier` column then verify the column `DataType` and its `Length`.

Comment: checked no working

Comment: which column is your GUId?

Comment: P2P_Request_SYSID, SYSID and EntityInstanceId

Comment: You should really read this: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: If you use SqlParameter, you don't have to convert the GUID into a string.See comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435918/880990. This one shows how to do it with parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436001/880990

Comment: Unique identifier in sql  server and Guid in C# are different. When column's datatype is unique identifier the value of it is expected to be generated by sql server. You are passing string values in the query and sql server can not convert string coming from outside to unique identifier. That's why you are seeing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User parameters and try to specify datatype for uniqueidentier

```
foreach (entity ent in _entity) 
{               
    con.Open();
    string query = @"INSERT INTO tblDemo (ContractType,P2P_Request_SYSID,EntityName,SYSID,
                     ETag,Name,EntityInstanceId,EntityVersion)
                     Values (@Type,@P2P_Request_SYSID,@EntityName,@SYSID,@ETag,@Name,
                     @EntityInstanceId,@EntityVersion)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ent.Type);
    cmd.Parameters.Add( "@P2P_Request_SYSID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 16 ).Value = ent.P2P_Request_SYSID;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityName", ent.EntityName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add( "@SYSID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 16 ).Value = ent.SYSID;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ETag", ent.ETag);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ent.Name);
    cmd.Parameters.Add( "@EntityInstanceId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 16 ).Value = ent.EntityInstanceId;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityVersion", ent.EntityVersion);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```